# Which is more preferred whenAllSuccess or a batch in Firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have a list of tasks like so:

```
val tasks: MutableList<Task<Void>> = mutableListOf()
for (uid in uids) {
    tasks.add(usersRef.document(uid).delete())
}
```

In order to delete all users, I pass this list to:

```
Tasks.whenAllSuccess<DocumentSnapshot>(tasks).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
    //My logic
}
```

This works great. However, I read that all these delete operations can also be added to a **batch**, but I have hard times understanding which is more likely to be used, `whenAllSuccess` or a `batch`?

Is there any other solution for deleting, for example, 250 users at once on the client-side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Batches and tasks are not really comparable.  They are different tools for different problems.

A [batch](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) is a Firestore concept, and is used when you have multiple documents to create, update, or delete, and they must be changed atomically.

Tasks are used for asynchronous programming.  You use `Tasks.whenAll` to create a new Task that completes when a list of other tasks have all completed.  Tasks are used across all of Firebase and Play services APIs.  They are not unique to Firestore.

Use whichever one solves your problem the best.  It's going to be up to you.  If all you're doing is deleting Firestore documents, and batch is probably easiest.

Comment: I just read that a batch has max 50 operations. If I need 250? Is there any issue if I add 250 tasks to Tasks.whenAll? Is it considered much?

Comment: Batches are limited to 500 documents.  If you need to exceed that, you can create a batch of batches in your code, each one up to 500.

Comment: Would be that a problem for example, to pass 500 tasks to `Tasks.whenAll`? Btw, thanks for answer and comment.

Comment: You can certainly try that.